# How to read variable value sent over Http Post and Get on AWS API Gateway Lambda using Javascript(Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am getting undefined on both POST and Get when I am doing it as bellow:

```
var name = event.queryStringParameters.name;
```

Is this a configuration I am missing or what?

Comment: Hello @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan I tried `JSON.parse(event.body)` it say `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: You should send your payload within the body. I have added a detailed example to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get payload within the body, you can use this solution as well.
Let say, you want to get the email from the event body. It should be like the below example.

**Sending request within the body**

[image]

the header will be "Content-Type: application/json"

and then in your lambda function, you are going to get the email like in the below screenshot.

[image]

```
JSON.parse(event.body).email
```

**When you send payload within the body, the fetch request will be as in below**

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({"email":"foo@bar.com"});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/contact", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

**PS: Above example, for cases, sending post requests within the body.**

Comment: Thank you, I was not reading body. I was reading it from event.queryStringParameters of which that was null:)